# Suppose $A^k$ is given then how to construct $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A^k$ is given then how to construct $A$?

For Simplicity assume $A^k$ is diagonalizable, then in principle, from $D = P^{-1} A^k P$, I can obtain $A$, $A = P D^{\frac{1}{k}} P^{-1}$ where $D^{\frac{1}{k}} = \textrm{diag}(\lambda_1^{\frac{1}{k}}, \cdots, )$

Due to the construction of $P$ and computing $P^{-1}$, this computation requires many computations. Is there another simple(?) method without computing the $P$ matrix from eigenvectors?

---

Naively By letting $B=A^k$ and letting $B_{ij} = (A\cdots A)_{ij}$ and solving $n^2$[Assume $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix] constraint equations I can solve for $A$. [But this approach is much worse than the previous one....]

Comment: The approach you wrote down is pretty much the simplest algebraic solution for $A^k$ diagonalisable. If $A^k$ is not diagonalisable, you can do something similar-ish per Jordan block.